# The problem with publish LaTex formulas in confluence

Tags: python, latex, python-sphinx, confluence

I generate rst files containing formulas in latex, then try to upload them to confluence

Example: File main.rst consist the formulas

```
:math:`\sqrt{3x-1}+(1+x)^2`
```

The conf file.py is located in the docs folder

Its contents

```py
extensions = [
    'sphinxcontrib.confluencebuilder',
    'sphinxcontrib.katex'
]

confluence_publish = True
confluence_space_key = '~user'
confluence_parent_page = 'Test rst generate'
confluence_server_url='https://confluence.com'
confluence_page_hierarchy = True
confluence_page_generation_notice = True
confluence_prev_next_buttons_location = 'top'
confluence_server_user='username'
confluence_server_pass='password'
```

I run it with the command

```bash
sphinx-build -b confluence docs _build/confluence
```

output:

```
Running Sphinx v7.2.6
WARNING: normalizing confluence url from https://confluence.com/ 
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
writing output... 
building [confluence]: targets for 2 source files that are out of date
reading sources... [100%] main
looking for now-outdated files... none found
checking consistency... done
preparing documents... WARNING: title conflict detected with 'index' and 'main'
WARNING: LaTeX command 'latex' cannot be run (needed for math display), check the imgmath_latex setting
done
copying assets... done
writing output... [100%] main
WARNING: ignoring node since no latex macro configured
WARNING: ignoring node since no latex macro configured
publishing documents... [100%] main
building intersphinx... done
publishing assets... [100%] objects.inv
Publish point: https://confluence.com/viewpage.action?pageId=209333449
build succeeded, 5 warnings.
```

As a result, the formula is not displayed

Comment: Did you see `WARNING: LaTeX command 'latex' cannot be run (needed for math display), check the imgmath_latex setting`?

Comment: i tryied used this parameter, i got an error
WARNING: unknown config value 'imgmath_latex' in override, ignoring
You know the normal one latex.exe which one will fit without problems?

Comment: It is better to explain normally, and not to put disadvantages, who came up with this at all?

Comment: I am not a sphinx or confluence expert, but there is an [explanation](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/math.html) for this setting.

Comment: I'm certainly not an expert.